# Error with keystore apk unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, keystore

When I try to build my apk on unity I get these to wrong messages:

1.

```
Win32Exception: ApplicationName='/Users/kristianstenberg/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.0/apksigner', CommandLine='sign --ks "/Users/kristianstenberg/Desktop/Platformer/VegardHansenStenberg.keystore" --ks-pass pass:"Balder123" --ks-key-alias "besquare" --key-pass pass:"Balder123" "/Users/kristianstenberg/Desktop/Platformer/Temp/StagingArea/Package.apk"', CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ()
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()
UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start (System.EventHandler exitCallback) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/Program.cs:44)
UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/Program.cs:28)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg, Int32 retriesOnFailure)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildAPK.SignPackage (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildAPK.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:263)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

2.

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Build failed with errors.
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x001b9] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:162 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00050] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:83 
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

I only get those messages when I have a keystore
Pleas help me

Answer (score 7):

This is caused by a known issue in Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.0 --
 it's missing`apksigner`. Until a newer version of Build Tools is released, there are two workarounds:

- switch to an older version of Android SDK Build Tools (e.g., `25.0.3`), or
- copy `apksigner` (and/or `apksigner.bat` on Windows) and `lib/apksigner.jar` from an older version of Build Tools to `build-tools/26.0.0/`.

See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3258 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62696222.

EDIT: Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.1 has been published. It contains `apksigner`.

Comment: This really saved my day! SDK 23 also didn't have these files for some reason

Comment: this needs to be voted correct answer. saved my day as well - i wish i found this 18 hours ago...